# Place dxf entities on mapbox and get coordinates of its like geojson of labs.mapbox.com/labs/dxf2geojson/dist/

Tags: three.js, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, ezdxf

**Requirement:**
I have to read dxf files entities which can be 2D building dimensions or road etc. Then i have to place it over the map and return the coordinates just like [labs.mapbox.com](https://labs.mapbox.com/labs/dxf2geojson/dist/) export the coordinates as geojson like the data below export by labs.mapbox.

**Approch**: For now i'm using python 'exdxf' package to read dxf file which return me entities information e.g in case of line it would be start/end points. Then i was thinking to draw those entities over a canvas (not sure) then place it over mapbox and get the coordinates where canvas is place export geojson of it is the final goal.

**Required help in**: Suggest me the right way to achieve this solution, i am open to choose any framework / language.

Thanks for your time

[image: labs.mapbox.com]
[image: geojson exported by labs.mapbox.com]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got a dxf file and want to export it as a geosjon file, using ezdxf python package is good but you have to do a lot of processing the dxf entities and stuff and it takes time to achieve what you want.

I suggest using **ogr2ogr** since this is a time saving approach. it is a library for working with geospatial data and you can convert data to different formats such as Geojson, shapefile and others.

you can easily convert your dxf file to a geojson file with :

```
ogr2ogr -f Geojson GEOJSON_FILE_NAME YOUR_DXF_FILE_NAME
```

I suggest reading [the documentation](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html)
first to get to know about this library and all the options it gives you for processing the data.

Comment: What if my dxf is not geo located? can i still able to create geo coordinate?

Comment: Thanks @fatemeh i tried ogr2ogr it does it work now i'm able to export dxf to geojson and can be disply over map